# Combine 3 arrays into Hash in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 arrays: `min`, `max` and `regions`. I want to create a hash for each `region` with corresponding `min` and `max` value. Something like this:

```
regions=["Region 1","Region 2",....]
min=["100","200",...]
max=["500","300",...]

#=> {"Region1"=>["100", "500"], "Region 2"=>["200", "300"], ...}
```

Here is my code:

```
@min = params[:min]
@max = params[:max]
@regions = params[:regions]
```

I have tried this so far, but didn't work:

```
@range_map = Hash[@regions.map{|r| [r, [@min.each.to_i,@max.each.to_i]]}]
```

All I want is a hash from 3 array and min and max to be converted to ***integer***.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this, using [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
range_map = regions.zip([min.map(&:to_i), max.map(&:to_i)].transpose).to_h

#=> {"Region1"=>[100, 500], "Region2"=>[200, 300]}
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/t03/1)

Comment: ...or `regions.zip(min.map(&:to_i).zip max.map(&:to_i)).to_h`. `zip` can always be used in place of `transpose`, but the reverse is not true when  the two arrays are different sizes.

Comment: Worked!! thanks guys..
Any yes the result looks same without transpose also